# Async map returns a mix of results and promises instead of just results

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

I have the below map and filter functions doing async inside.

```
  console.log('kycPendingProviders:', kycPendingProviders)
  const incompleteKYCClaims = kycPendingProviders
    .map(async (p) => {
      const provider = await getProviderOrThrow(p.tin)
      console.log('provider:', provider)
    
      // check who submitted the current KYC
      if (provider.kycSubmissionInfo?.submissionRequest.submitterUUID !== currentUserID) return Promise.reject()

      return toProviderRelationshipClaims({ tin: p.tin, role: ProviderUserSubRoles.ky, status: 'KYCInDraft' })
    })
    .filter((claim) => claim) as unknown as Array<ProviderRelationshipClaims>
  console.log('incompleteKYCClaims:', incompleteKYCClaims)
```

Tried both `if (provider.kycSubmissionInfo?.submissionRequest.submitterUUID !== currentUserID) return` with the idea that `filter` will remove `undefined` entries and `if (provider.kycSubmissionInfo?.submissionRequest.submitterUUID !== currentUserID) return Promise.reject()` versions.

When the condition is not met, I am getting as a result `[ Promise { <pending> } ]` while I need an `undefined` value to be removed from the results array by the subsequent `filter()`.

I have a version with `for of` loop. That seemed to be working correctly. Why is `map()` not returning a value [here `undefined`], but a pending promise? How do I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: The `.map()` method won't do anything special with an `async` callback. It calls the callback as if it is a regular function, and the Promise it returns will be treated as the value to be added to the array `.map()` creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue and obtain the desired behavior, you can use Promise.all() to await all the promises returned by map() and then use the filter() function on the resolved values. Here's an example:

```
console.log('kycPendingProviders:', kycPendingProviders);

const incompleteKYCClaims = await Promise.all(
  kycPendingProviders.map(async (p) => {
    const provider = await getProviderOrThrow(p.tin);
    console.log('provider:', provider);

    if (provider.kycSubmissionInfo?.submissionRequest.submitterUUID !== currentUserID) {
      return undefined; // or null, or any other value that signifies removal
    }

    return toProviderRelationshipClaims({ tin: p.tin, role: ProviderUserSubRoles.ky, status: 'KYCInDraft' });
  })
);

const filteredKYCClaims = incompleteKYCClaims.filter((claim) => claim !== undefined) as Array<ProviderRelationshipClaims>;
console.log('filteredKYCClaims:', filteredKYCClaims);
```